# How do I implement cascading dropdown using golang's templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, go

**Scenario:**

I have a cascade scenario, where values in second dropdown depends upon first. I have three templates "layout", "input" and "inner".

**Attempt:**

I'm making ajax call on change of first dropdown in "input" template and stuck with handling the response returned. Currently I found a way to fix it by replacing html of second dropdown. But, I think this is not the better way to handle. I want something in line of rendering templates where I do not need to amend html.

please help in acheiving the task in better way or point to some wiki. **Only Standard Library**

Thanks,

***Layout.html*:**
http://play.golang.org/p/LikKy6rf3-

***Input.html*:**
http://play.golang.org/p/wM7EpPdXuM

***Inner.html*:**
http://play.golang.org/p/xFpInKZfFT

***Main.go*:**
http://play.golang.org/p/cxtJU-Lhi1

Comment: Any pointers about partial rendering of go template will also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the higher level you have 2 options:

- Either send all the values for the dropdown lists (e.g. as a tree) and change the values on the 2nd and 3rd level when the dropdown of a higher level changes (suitable for small lists, unsuitable for large dataset)
- Or the one you chose: when selection changes, you make an AJAX call (triggered from `onchange`) and you populate the list from the results.

### Elaborating #2: populating list from the AJAX call result

You also have 2 options to do this:

- Either the AJAX call returns HTML call which you can simply use to replace the inner HTML of the HTML `<select>` tag.
- Or the AJAX call may only return the data (e.g. encoded using JSON), and a Javascript code can build the content of the list.

#### AJAX returning HTML

The AJAX call may return the complete HTML code needed to be replaced as the inner HTML of the `<select>`. To achieve this at server side, you can create/separate the HTML template responsible only to generate the HTML code of this, for example:

```
{{define "innerList"}}
    {{range .}}
        <option value="{{.Key}}">{{.Text}}</option>
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

You can execute only this template like this:

```
// tmpl is the collection of your templates
values := ... // Load/construct the values
tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "innerList", values)
```

Here `values` is a slice of the following structure:

```
type Pair struct {
    Key string
    Text string
}
```

#### Building `<select>` content with Javascript

The AJAX call may return a JSON datastructure, an array/list of `value;text` pairs from which you add the `<option>` child tags yourself.

To add an `<option>` to a `<select>` tag:

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = "1234";
option.text = "Kiwi";
x.add(option);
```

So basically what you need to do is remove current children of the `<select>`, iterate over the list received as the response and add a new `<option>` tag constructed from each.

Comment: thanks @icza for your detail description. I'm already populating dropdown by rendering html return via ajax in input.html
  
`$("#divPlaceholderForDropDown").empty();
$("#divPlaceholderForDropDown").append(data); 
  `
Don't we have anything parallel to partial rendering of go templates ?

Comment: @VKS The easiest is if you define it as a separate template and you can simply execute only this template. This is described in my answer.

Comment: Wow that means I had already done it perfectly ;) I had defined separate template for dropdown and was executing it via `tmpl.Executetemplate...` i was not happy to replace the html at the client side & was looking for something like `{{template "inner"}}` which would do the job without me replacing it. But seems this is the only way .. I'm accepting your answer.. thanks